# Смена статуса на "Нет в наличии" OpenCart 2.0.1

Tags: opencart

Здравствуйте. 
Увидел несколько готовых решений, одно из них было "Grayimage". Установил, но не помогло. В чем может быть проблема?
Как я могу сделать, чтобы товара, которого нет в наличии была надпись "Нет в наличии" и он был недоступен для покупки?
Заранее спасибо..

Comment: увидел, что можно поставить "out of stock". Но хотелось бы какое-то более красивое решение...

Answer (score 2):

**Для opencart 2.x+ :**

В `catalog/controller/product/product.php` есть массив `$product_info`. В нём находится коллекция атрибутов товара. Далее по коду вы можете найти переменную `$product_info['quantity']` - в ней содержится остаток. Далее найдите следующий блок:

```
if ($product_info['quantity'] <= 0) {
    $data['stock'] = $product_info['stock_status'];
} elseif ($this->config->get('config_stock_display')) {
    $data['stock'] = $product_info['quantity'];
} else {
    $data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_instock');
}
```

Здесь формируется переменная со значением in stock/out of stock. Добавте туда свой маркер, который будет нести, например, 1 или 0 в зависимости от наличия на складе:

```
if ($product_info['quantity'] <= 0) {
    $data['stock'] = $product_info['stock_status'];
    $data['stock_marker'] = 0; // нет на складе.
} elseif ($this->config->get('config_stock_display')) {
    $data['stock'] = $product_info['quantity'];
} else {
    $data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_instock');
    $data['stock_marker'] = 1; // есть на складе.
}
```

Далее, в файле представления `catalog/view/theme/default(ваша_тема)/product/product.tpl` найдите блок, в котором выводятся количество и кнопка "купить". Оберните этот блок в конструкцию:

```
if ( $stock_marker ) {
    // выводим количество и кнопку "купить", может что-то ещё
} else {
    // не выводим количество и кнопку "купить"
    // какой-нибудь мессадж, что товара нет и всё такое.
}
```

Как менять подписи статуса наличия, думаю, поймёте исходя из описанного.